# Get the text box value using jquery with dynamic generated tag IDs?

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I have two text boxes:

```
<input type="text" id="xxxxx_SearchBox_xxxxxx_InputBox">
<input type="text" id="xxxxx_xxxxxx_InputBox">
```

How can I get the value of the second text box? `xxxx` are not constant and vary all the time so I can't rely on them.

```
$("input[type='text'][id*='_InputBox']").val()
```

Will it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**eq**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) jquery function to access elements by index returned by selector,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/hmN9X/)**

```
$("input[type='text'][id*='_InputBox']").eq(1).val()
```

Answer (score 1):

"[Attribute Ends With Selector [name$="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)" selector might be better, but if you could add an "`InputBox`" class name on the server's side, that would make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[type='text']:not([id*=SearchBox])").val() // phew
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[id$='_InputBox']:not('[id*=SearchBox]')").val();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/9yRhn/1/).